# Creating a PHP Socket Server Heartbeat for Penny Auction Site

Tags: php, ajax, serversocket

I believe that this is something a lot of people want to do but that isn't clearly explained anywhere that I have found.

I am developing a penny auction site for a client and I need to build it so that everyone sees an accurate auction timer that is synced between users. Through research I have come to the conclusion that I need to set up a socket server.

I know very little about this and was hoping someone could explain how this functionality should be set up.

Comment: this is the official php socket documentation it would be a great place to start.  Even ify ou don't understand it all yet it will introduce you to all the functions php offers http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

Comment: The javascript would work fine for something like ebay but with penny auctions its different because bids in the final seconds increases the time by a specific amount of seconds. So when someone bids and the timer goes from say 5 seconds to 15 seconds everyone needs to see that. Ajax requests every second would be pretty hard on the server correct?

Comment: I see the problem. Sockets would solve your problem very well but they are not well supported currently. I would use small ajax requests for this. The server should be able to handle that. You could implement a dual solution using sockets if possible with an ajax/comet fallback.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you think a little complicated here. A simple Javascript countdown should do the trick. Place it on the top of the document and start it right away (not on page load) and it should be more or less in sync on every client. It's not 100% accurate but it works for ebay.

Add an ajax refresh to resync it if you fell the need to.

Consider all clients actions delayed by the internet anyway so even if the timer is a whole 1 second off it should not make a big difference.

Comment: This is a great option, however... what happens if the client disables javascript? look into push services such as socket.io or nodejs.org

Comment: nodejs has js = javascript in his name. There is no way without JS or Flash or something even more evil to do this. If the client disables Javascript you show him: "Sorry, this page does not work without javascript" ;)

Comment: You could embed an iframe that has a constant refresh interval set in the meta.

Also, make sure that any time sent back with your form is verified with your server. Otherwise, clients could manipulate their host clock, to put in the last bid early, or slip in a last second bid after the bidding ends.

Comment: how would we reset the timer for a specific item across all sessions everytime a user clicks bid on that specific item

Comment: @MohammedSohailEbrahim Make an ajax query that updates the clock and call that function with `window.setInterval()`

Comment: still not exactly sure of the design...moreso when using asp